# How to show the variable name on the exception message when the assertion fails using FluentAssertions?

Tags: fluent-assertions

I am trying to create some Assertion classes using the FluentAssertions library. This is the Assertion code:

```cs
public AndConstraint<MyTaskAssertions> Work(string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
{
    Execute.Assertion
        .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
        .WithExpectation("Expected {context:mytask} to work{reason}, ")
        .Given(() => Subject)
        .ForCondition(x => x.Works)
        .FailWith("but it doesn't");

    return new AndConstraint<MyTaskAssertions>(this);
}
```

And this is my test:

```cs
var t = new MyTask {Works=false};
t.Should().Work();
```

Everything works fine, except for the fact that instead of the variable name `t`, "**mytask**" is displayed on the exception message:

> Expected mytask to work, but it doesn't

I've read the [Extensibility](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/) page on the Documentation, and I also checked the source code for the built-in assertions, but I am still not sure what exactly I am missing for the exception message to show the actual variable name instead of what is after the "context:" placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark your method with `[CustomAssertion]`. See also https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#subject-identification

Comment: Dennis, in the article https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#subject-identification should the phrase “ since only .NET Standard 2.0 and the full .NET Framework support getting direct access to the current stack trace,” be updated to “.NET Standard 2.0  **or greater** ”?